# Secure SCORM content in Offline player

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, desktop-application, offline

I am developing Desktop Application (which launches a zip containing index.html in browser). I want to secure that zip from end user so that zip's content can not be accessed without App.

***NOTE: zip will consist couple of HTML, JS and CSS files and my app will consume it by displaying it's index.html file in browser.***

I can encrypt my content but before using/launching content's index.html (through my app in browser) I will have to decrypt and extract zip into local file system. At that time user will get access of decrypted content. Is there any way to somehow keep decrypted content in in-memory from where browser can access HTML file and display them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you have:

1. **one of in-memory filesystems**: the simplest and the least useful that answer directly the question "*a way to somehow keep decrypted content in in-memory from where browser can access HTML file and display them*". If you are going to use a standard browser, the content should be accessible to it, so the user can read it as well.
2. **local web server**: no much better, if you keep using standard browser. You can use something like electron's webview or alternative embedded browsers in combination with client certification. This way you can ensure the content is being visible only in legitimate browser. It can be done with nodejs (+ desktop integration) and will protect the content from non-technical users. Anyone with a bit of coding skills will be able to reverse-engineer it tho.
3. **custom web browser**: a regular compiled desktop app. You will need to implement your own browser, and can decrypt the archive directly in the app's memory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I will have to go with the second option. But can you tell me how music apps or apps like Lynda handle these situations?

Comment: I see no reason why music apps would package their content in SCORM, so there is no need to use a browser at the first place. Not sure how premium Lynda works, but it shouldn't be hard to figure it out once you have it installed. If they are using SCORM at all, it must be 3rd option, since they provide clients for limited list of platforms only. The first 2 options are  easily portable.

Comment: Even I also dont think music apps or Lynda use SCORM, I meant to ask how they keep their content (mp3, avi) secure in user's machine (mobile, desktop). But yea, can be figured out. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no problem to keep encrypted content on the user's machine. The problem is that SCORM player implies use of an html browser with javascript support, so the content must be decrypted first and be accessible by the end user. If you are not limited to SCORM spec, you can use any custom-built content viewer that decrypts it on the fly, use DRM, and the whole spectre of modern technologies emerged long after SCORM was designed. SCORM aims slightly different goals and does not particularly address copyright protection.